# Insert Data from a Temp Table into Multiple Joined Tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I'd to here some opinions on what the best approach for the following would be.

I've imported some data from a client into a temp table, cleaned it up, and now need to insert the new records into to our system.

The client has internal and external locations, each has different information stored about them but in some instances (reporting or assigning items) all locations should be treated as just a location the type (internal or external) is not important.

I have 4 tables:

1. `Temp_Table` - containing the data from the client about external locations
2. `Locations` - containing the a `Location ID`, update time etc. This links to the other location tables depending on the type of location
3. `Internal Locations`
4. `External Locations`

**`Locations` table contains -**

- `Location_ID int PK`
- `?External_Location_ID? int`
- `?Internal_Location_ID? int`
- other irrelevant info

**`External Locations` table contains**

- `External_Location_ID int PK`
- `?Location_ID?`
- other irrelevant info

**Question 1**

Is it best to have `?External_Location_ID?` in the `Locations` table OR to store the `?Location_ID?` in the `External_Locations` table? This will always be a 1 to 1 relationship and indexed.

**Question 2**

I now want to get the data from the temp table into the external locations table and the locations table, one table will have to reference the other.

This would be easy to do looping through the table one row at a time by using cursors (which I won't use) or a while loop but is there a more effective way from a clean coding point of view an performance.

Could I:

1. loop through with a while statement and insert each row probably via a stored procedure
2. Do something with a function like `Select my_Insert_Func(Val_1, Val_2, Val_3) From #Temp_Table;` then return 0 or 1 on the function. I've never tried to use a function to insert data and it seems to be 'wrong' I think of functions as returning data but could it could and would it be better/worse than a while loop?
3. Any other idea an SQL genius can come up with.

Performance isn't a massive issue with this as it will only run once a night and isn't a large data set but from experience clients 'lie', once a day becomes every 15 minutes and a small data set becomes massive, plus getting this right will allow me to carry the same theories forward.

Thanks for any replies.

PS I'm looking for a set based way if possible rather than looping

---

Thanks for the input guys.

@HGLEM
Useful link, all the other queries I have are set based already but as this one requires two input statements I can't think of a set based way to do this which is what I was after (just couldn't think of the term set based when writing it). That said I've just tidied up one of my queries using the Merge function in the link you sent, now much neater and easier to read, I still need to get the link into the locations table though, shame MERGE doesn't allow EXEC only DELETE, SELECT and UPDATE are allowed.

```
MERGE Locations_Internal AS Target
USING (select #CSVTemp.Val_1, #CSVTemp.Val_2, #CSVTEMP.Val_3, #CSVTemp.Val_4 from #CSVTemp)
    AS Source
ON (Target.Val_1 = Source.Val_1 )
WHEN MATCHED AND 
        ((COALESCE(Source.Val_2, '') <> COALESCE(Target.Val_2, '')
        OR COALESCE(Source.Val_3, '') <> COALESCE(Target.Val_3, '') 
        OR COALESCE(Source.Val_4, '') <> COALESCE(Target.Val_4, '')))
    THEN
        UPDATE
            SET Target.Val_1= Source.Val_1,
                Target.Val_2= Source.Val_2,
                Target.Val_4= Source.Val_3,
                Target.Val_5= Source.Val_5,
                Target.Row_Updated = GETDATE()
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(Val_1, Val_2, Val_3, Val_4, Row_Updated)
    VALUES(Source.Val_1, Source.Val_2, Source.Val_3, Source.Val_4, GETDATE());
```

Comment: if you describe exacly the tables, someone will give you the right query for you.

Comment: WHy on earth would you loop at all. You can write set-based inserts, see link for how:http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 1):

*converted the comments in an answer.*

Question 1: what your queries will be? If you (most likely) will know the location and then want to know the external location of that location, then put the FK in the location table. if instead you will happen to know the external location and will want to know the corresponding location, do the opposite.

Question 2: you don't need "functions", just a couple of `SQL INSERT` instructions (in a transaction). It will take records from the temp table and insert them in the destination table(s).

If you describe exacly the tables, someone will give you the right query for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. Its good to know it i'm doing it right, I just wanted to know if there was a better method really.
 
The for the queries I run have placed the FK in the locations table so good to know your recommend it either way.
 
I'm ok on getting the 2 INSERT queries right and placing them in a transaction so no help needed there.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: External_Location_Id and Internal_Location_Id will never match.
If the above assumption is true then you can consolidate this to just LocationId.

Looping Inside Stored Proc:
I have done this by using LABELS and GOTO and it works great!
Here's a code stub

CREATE PROCEDURE spProcessClientData
as
DECLARE @RecCount int
DECLARE @I int

CREAT TABLE #TempData
(
RowId int identity(1,1),
/*
ClientData1
ClientData2
ClientData3
*/
)

/*
Insert ClientData into #TempData table
The RowId identity value will be used to control looping
*/

SET @RecCount = (SELECT MAX(RowId) FROM #TempData)
SET @I = 0

WHILE @I < @RecCount
BEGIN
  SET @I = @I + 1
  GOTO DetailProcessing
  DetailProcessingReturn:
END

DROP #TempTable
RETURN

DetailProcessing:
/*
Put all the processing logic
you want to perform for each
record where @I = #TempData.RowId
When done return to the loop
using another GOTO and Label
*/
GOTO DetailProcessingReturn